# Rename multiple pdf files after reading corresponding text files present in different folder using bat script

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-7

**PROBLEM**

I am working on a bat script which should be able to read 1000 of text files from a location say Z:/Demo/Text and after reading the stored values the script is able to rename the corresponding pdf files present at say Z:/Demo/PDF. The text files are named and read in the following manner: SomeDate_Part1.txt, SomeDate_Part2.txt....

And the PDF files possess the same attribute just the file extension is different.

**Renaming logic:**

If the value stored in the SomeDate_Part1.txt file is AAA then the corresponding PDF file ie SomeDate_Part1.pdf should be renamed as CGI1_filename.pdf and if the stored value is BBB then it should be renamed as CGI2_filename.pdf.

I wrote a few lines and was able to successfully read all the text files from the folder. The code I wrote is:

```
@echo off
for %%x in (\Demo\Text\*.txt) do (
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%%~fx") do (
        if "%%a"=="AAA" echo %%a
        if "%%a"=="BBB" echo %%a
    )
)
pause
```

How can I solve the remaining issue?

Comment: I don't understand your "renaming logic". If the _line_ stored in a .txt file is ZZZ the corresponding .pdf file should be renamed CGI26.pdf? This "logic" gives just 26 different names, so you can _not_ use it to rename 1000 files...

Comment: So what is stopping you from changing the `echo %%a` to the rename command you want to use?

Comment: @Aacini there are only two possible stored values AAA or BBB, it does not follow the alphabetical series.

Comment: Squashman- As I am not familiar with batch files I am unable to write down the code where the program will go to the PDF folder and will iterate through each file and will rename it

Comment: Should the resulting filename be `CGI1_SomeDate_Part1.pdf` or `CGI2_SomeDate_Part1.pdf`?

Comment: @lit yes please

Comment: @V15720002000: In the original question you did _not_ stated that the new name should include the `SomeDate_Part1.pdf` part; hence my comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "AAA=1"
set "BBB=2"

for %%x in (\Demo\Text\*.txt) do (
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%%~Fx") do (
        ren "\Demo\PDF\%%~Nx.pdf" "CGI!%%a!_%%~Nx.pdf"
    )
)
pause
```

This code is practically a copy of the original with just two differences:

- The values of `AAA` and `BBB` are set to `1` and `2`, respectively. These values are stated in the question decription.
- The two `if` commands that just display the values in the text files are changed by the desired `ren` command, as requested in the question description. In the `ren` command, the location of the .pdf file is set to `\Demo\PDF` as stated in the question. The new part of the name is comprised by `CGI!%%a!_`. The `%%a` contain the value stored in the text file that is `AAA` or `BBB` accordingly to the description. In this way, the `!%%a!` part becomes `!AAA!` or `!BBB!` that is replaced by the value of `AAA` or `BBB` via delayed expansion, so the new file name is `CGI1_SomeDate_Part1.pdf` or `CGI2_SomeDate_Part2.pdf` as requested in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to push ahead into PowerShell, this code might do what you want. I have not tested it. When you are confident that the files will be renamed correctly, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Rename-Item` cmdlet.

Save this script as `Rename-PdfFiles.ps1`.

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Path '\Demo\Text' -Filter '*.txt' |
    ForEach-Object {
        $fn = $_.BaseName
        $pdfname = "\Demo\Text\$($fn).pdf"

        if (Test-Path -Path $pdfname) {
            $mark = Get-Content -Path $_
            if ($mark -eq 'AAA') { $prefix = 'CGI1' } else { $prefix = 'CGI2' }
            Rename-Item -Path $pdfname -NewName "$($prefix)_$(fn).pdf" -WhatIf
        }
    }
```

Run it from a cmd shell using:

```
powershell -NoProfile -File .\Rename-PdfFiles.ps1
```

If you cannot get past making a .bat file, this might work. I have not tested this either. If it outputs the correct `RENAME` commands, remove the `echo` at the beginning of the line.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR %%x IN ('\Demo\Text\*.txt') DO (
    SET "FN=%%~nx"
    SET "PDFNAME=\Demo\Text\!FN!.pdf"

    IF EXIST "!PDFNAME! (
        SET /P "MARK=" <"%%~x"
        IF "!MARK!" == "AAA" ( SET "PREFIX=CGI1" ) else ( SET "PREFIX=CGI2" )
        echo RENAME "!PDFNAME!" "!PREFIX!_!FN!.pdf"
    )
```